# Rails Associations - How to get and Object Instead of Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models in Rails. One is for Users and one is for Jobs that can be owned by users. In the User model, I have a `has_many` association, and in the Jobs object I have a `belongs_to` association. Jobs have an `owner` column which is the user id of the owner (associated via a foreign key).

`User: (id, name, email)`

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Job', foreign_key: :owner
end
```

`Job: (id, owner, job_code)`

```
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :owner
end
```

This works fine in one direction: `User.first.jobs` will display a list of all of the Jobs that belong to that user. Unfortunately however, if I try to user `Job.first.owner`, I get simply the user's id integer, not a user object. What a I missing to be able to select the owner without having to re-query the database to get a user by ID?

Answer (score 3):

```
1st Issue:
 Don't use "object" as your model name, this keyword is already reserved.
```

Let's say you have got user model and job model, one user has got many jobs.

```
User (id, name, email) Job (id, job_code, owner)

here, the owner column holds the userID to which the job belongs to. 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, class_name: 'Job', foreign_key: 'owner'
end


class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user , class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner'
end
```

Now:

```
User.first.jobs #will give you first users jobs. 
Job.first.user #will give you the owner info of the job
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I am not using Object as the model name, that is just for this question (and it's confusing). I will edit it in the initial question for clarity.

Comment: Sure, no issue, Instead of object I assumed it to be 'job' and added required association. Am again assuming you have owner column in the job table which connects it with user. Please try this & let me know if that does not help :)

Comment: I have updated the original question for clarity. Unfortunately, ```Job.first.owner``` still results in an integer for the user, but no user object (so ```Job.first.owner.name``` results in an undefined method).

Comment: Look, you have not mentioned the class_name yet.
user.rb :   has_many :jobs, class_name: 'Job', foreign_key: 'owner' and  job.rb:   belongs_to :user , class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner' 
mention class Name :)

Comment: I actually tried it with class names after you used that initially, and it doesn't fix anything. ```Job.first.owner``` is still an integer. Edited OP (again) to reflect the ```class_name``` option used.

Comment: am sharing my code in bitbucket, simply perform bundle install & then go in console & check the queries.
https://bitbucket.org/Aj150491/association-app/